# UnicodeDecodeError while installing Quail with pip

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install Quial package with `pip`
(`python -m pip install quail)`

But it gives me this error and as I can not change the file I did not find a solution for:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1279, in _build_paths
        return os.pathsep.join(unique_paths)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xee in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
   ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\3bd6~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-upycdp\\multiprocessing\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\3bd6~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-zbpopy\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\3bd6~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-upycdp\multiprocessing\
```

Comment: `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` in cmd and then try run pip again

Comment: and it will not damege enything else?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems that you have non-Unicode characters in your path (possibly, judging from your name, in Hebrew :) This is more or less an instance of a [known bug in Pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2501). You might want to try it in Python 3, or just updating Pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` (for Windows, otherwise just `pip install --upgrade pip`).

Comment: alredy tried that and it didnt help, thank you any way!